Tracking First-Time (or n-time) Activation Events in Mixpanel
I am using Mixpanel to track user interactions with our app, specifically focusing on three events: Message Sent, Add Contact, and Payment Generated.
I have defined an "Activated User" as a user who has:

Generated at least 1 Add Contact OR

Generated at least 1 Payment Generated event OR

Sent 5 Message Sent events


I want to count only the first time a user meets any of these criteria, effectively tracking when a user becomes an "Activated User" for the first time. Additionally, I want to analyze how many new users become Activated Users on a weekly or monthly basis.
How can I set up a report in Mixpanel to achieve this?
